# In .NET MAUI Xamarin, how can I add a search bar (and other buttons) in AppShell to appear on the top of every ShellContent?

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

I am new to .NET MAUI and Xamarin in general so please bare with me.

I have several `<ShellContent>` in my AppShell.xaml file but I want all of them to have common buttons, labels, and search on the top. The worst way I can see is copying XAML into every view on `<ShellContent>` but I am wondering if there is a way to share XAML markup between all the pages in `<ShellContent>` or have AppShell display another view on the top and render the pages below it. How should I go about accomplishing this?

Here is how my AppShell.xaml looks now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Shell
    x:Class="G.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:G"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent
                Title="InventoryPage"
                Route="InventoryPage"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:InventoryPage}" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Home"
                Route="MainPage"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />

        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I have tried using `<Shell.TitleView>` but nothing shows up on screen for MacOS or iOS.

Comment: Have all your pages inherit from a common base class that implements the common ui elements

Comment: @Jason do you know where I can find a link or resource about creating the base class? I still am unsure how ShellContent, the XAML, and CS files relate. Thanks!

Comment: https://thewissen.io/create-a-kickass-banking-app-using-a-basepage-in-xamarin/